# How can a variable declared in composition be used for dynamic rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want a vue js v3 project using composition api, I have declared a variable like this

```
setup() {
    const showInvoiceItemForm = true;

    return { showInvoiceItemForm };
  },
```

Now I want to display a form when a button is clicked and a function is called like this

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <InvoiceItem
    :form="form"
    v-if="this.showInvoiceItemForm"
    ></InvoiceItem>

    <div class="mt-20 flex flex-row justify-between space-x-8">
        <BreezeButton type="button" @click="addInvoiceItem"
            >Add Item</BreezeButton
        >
        <BreezeButton>Generate Invoice</BreezeButton>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the method is like this

```
addInvoiceItem() {
    this.showInvoiceItemForm = true;
    console.log(this.showInvoiceItemForm);
},
```

From the console, I can see that the value of `showInvoiceItemForm` is set to `true` but the form is never shown. It looks like the value never really changes, so what is the proper way to use the composition api variable.

Comment: I believe it is `v-if="showInvoiceItemForm"`

Comment: @PeterKrebs using `v-if="showInvoiceItemForm"` still does not display the form when the `add item` button is clicked but in console I can see the value is `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, (it is necessary to show the form when the button is clicked), then I hope this solution will help you.

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <form v-if="showInvoiceItemForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type text here">
    </form>

    <div>
      <button @click="addInvoiceItem">Add Item</button>
      <button>Generate Invoice</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup () {

    let showInvoiceItemForm = ref(false);

    function addInvoiceItem() {
      showInvoiceItemForm.value = !showInvoiceItemForm.value;
      console.log(showInvoiceItemForm.value);
    };
    
    return {showInvoiceItemForm, addInvoiceItem}
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, if you not sure in "value change", you can install vue.js devtools, it's very useful.

Comment: Great! solution fixed the issue for me. But. why didn't setting `showInvoiceItemForm = true` work but `showInvoiceItemForm.value = true` work?

Comment: Thanks! If you console.log without value, it print for you object with values. So, ref() function create object, and then you get value from object. Im not sure, but it works like or close to this

Comment: It works like that. In `<script>`, you you can refer to the value by `refName.value`, and in `<template>`, you access it just by `refName`. To avoid this verbosity, they added [reactivity transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactivity-transform).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make your variable reactive with `ref` or `reactive` and move all to setup function:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: "#demo",
  setup() {
    const showInvoiceItemForm = ref(false);
    const addInvoiceItem = () => {
      showInvoiceItemForm.value = true;
      console.log(showInvoiceItemForm.value);
    }
    return { showInvoiceItemForm, addInvoiceItem };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input v-if="showInvoiceItemForm" />
    <div class="mt-20 flex flex-row justify-between space-x-8">
      <button type="button" @click="addInvoiceItem"
        >Add Item</button>
      <button>Generate Invoice</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works nicely here but I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: "showInvoiceItemForm" is read-only`

Comment: @Mena hey mate, did you make `showInvoiceItemForm` reactive, if not it is `const` so change it to `let`

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I had to change from const to let and then also set the value of `showInvoiceItemForm`

Comment: Nice , but maybe is better idea to make that variable reactive with ref or reactive

Answer (score 0):

[Vue 3 Composition API](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage)

> `setup()` itself does not have access to the component instance - `this` will have a value of `undefined` inside `setup()`. You can access Composition-API-exposed values from Options API, but not the other way around.

You do not have to use `this`. See if changing `v-if="this.showInvoiceItemForm"` to  `v-if="showInvoiceItemForm"` works, same for when you set it.

Try [this code snippet](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbiAgbGV0IHNob3dJbnZvaWNlSXRlbSA9ICRyZWYoZmFsc2UpO1xuICBcbiAgY29uc3Qgc3dpdGNoU2hvd0ludm9pY2VJdGVtID0gKCkgPT4ge1xuICAgIHNob3dJbnZvaWNlSXRlbSA9ICFzaG93SW52b2ljZUl0ZW07XG4gIH1cbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxoMT57eyBzaG93SW52b2ljZUl0ZW0gfX08L2gxPlxuICBcbiAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2sucHJldmVudD1cInN3aXRjaFNob3dJbnZvaWNlSXRlbVwiPlxuICAgIFRvZ2dsZSBTaG93XG4gIDwvYnV0dG9uPlxuICA8ZGl2IHYtaWY9XCJzaG93SW52b2ljZUl0ZW1cIj5cbiAgICBub3cgeW91IHNlZSBtZSwgbm93IHlvdSBkb250XG4gIDwvZGl2PlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59In0=) and see if it helps.

Comment: changed to `v-if="showInvoiceItemForm"` and in the `addInvoiceItem` method, I changed to `showInvoiceItemForm = true;` but got  the error
> Uncaught ReferenceError: showInvoiceItemForm is not defined

Comment: I wrote a little snippet in Vue playground. See if it's too different from your code and if it can help you fix your problem. I've included the link in the answer.